# How can I perform this simple equality comparison?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T, TId> : IRepository<T, TId>
    where T : class, IEntityWithTypedId<TId>
    where TId : IEquatable<TId>, IComparable<TId>
{
    public T FindById(TId id)
    {
        T entity;

        using (this.Context) // This simply returns the NHibernate Session
        {
            var entities = from e in this.Context.Get()
                           // where e.Id.Equals(id)
                           where e.Id == id
                           select e;

            entity = entities.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

If I use the `where e.Id == id` clause, I get the error:

> error CS0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId'

error even though I've told the compiler that `TId` must implement `IEquatable` and `IComparable`

If I use the `where e.Id.Equals(id)` clause, the code will compile, but I get a NotSupported Exception from NHibernate when it executes the query on the `FirstOrDefault` line.

I know that I must be missing something in the design however the solution has eluded me for several days.

Comment: Why don't you avoid the problem entirely and use session.Get<T>(id)?

Comment: You should be comparing their keys, not the entities themselves...

Comment: Using Get<T>(id) would be the simplest solution to this question... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might seem intuitive, operators (`==`, `<`, `>`, etc.) have nothing to do with interfaces like `IComparable`, `IEquatable`, etc. Unfortunately, operators can't be applied to generic types.

Unlike functions like `Equals`, operators are static and therefore not polymorphic. Since it's not possible to access static members of generic types, operators are inaccessible.